# I want to call Action Method of controller and return View on Kendo grid row click

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Below is my kendo grid code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataSource>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Quote_ID).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Ticket_ID).Groupable(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Channel).Groupable(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Agent_Alias).Groupable(true).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Shipping_Carrier).Groupable(true).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Quote_ID).Title("View 
        Details").Groupable(false)

        .Template(@<text>
            @Html.ActionLink("Show Product Details", "GridRowSummary", 
        "GridOrderSummary")</text>);                                                         

    })
```

From ActionLink I am trying to call Action Method of my controller.

```
Below My controller code

public ActionResult GridRowSummary()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Template` will work when using Ajax bound grids e.g:

```
columns.Template(c => @Html.ActionLink("GridRowSummary", "GridOrderSummary", new { id = c.Id, }));
```

If not using Ajax bound grids use `ClientTemplate` attribute on the column, along with a method to display the associated data, if required e.g.:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Quote_ID).Title("View Details").Groupable(false)
    .ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#=Quote_ID#", "GridRowSummary", new { ID = "#=ID#" }).ToHtmlString());
```

There is a third method (a little messy) which allows you to add custom buttons/icons etc e.g:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Quote_ID).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + @Url.Action("GridRowSummary", "GridOrderSummary", new { id = "#=Id#" }) + "' class='btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i>  Link</a>" );
```

### EDIT

From looking through the [FAQ](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-use-javascript-functions-in-column-client-templates) section, found an even neater solution where you can pass controller name and your `Quote_ID` parameter (although this way does involve setting up a Javascript function):

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Quote_ID).ClientTemplate("#= getDetails(data) #");

<script>
function getDetails(data) {
    var action = '@Url.Action("NameOfMethod", "NameOfController")';

    var html = kendo.format("<a href='{0}/{1}'>Link</a>",
        action,
        data.Quote_ID
    );

    return html;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can I pass controller name. And I also want to pass "Quote_ID" as a parameter

Comment: Using the `href` solution, I think you should just be able to pass `Quote_ID` instead of `Id`.. Something like `.ClientTemplate("<a href='"+Url.Action("MethodName","ControllerName")+"/#=Quote_ID#'>Link</a>");`. Some more examples can be found in the [FAQ](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-use-action-links) section of Telerik docs.

Comment: If JS can be used, I added another potential solution which is neat too :)

Comment: I am not getting data in data.Quote_ID

Answer (score 0):

For client template below code works. Replace is necessary.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Quote_ID).Title("View Details").Groupable(false)
             .ClientTemplate(
            @Html.ActionLink("#=Quote_ID#", "Summary", new { Quote_ID = "Id" 
}).ToHtmlString().Replace("Id", "#=Quote_ID#"));
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution works for me.

```
 .Events(events =>
    {
        events.Change("onRowSelected");
    })

function onRowSelected(e) {
            debugger;
            var gview = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            //Getting selected item
            var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
            var ticketId = selectedItem["Ticket_ID"];
            window.location.href = "/GridOrderSummary/GridRowSummary?
            ticketId=" + ticketId;
        }

//Controller code
```

public class GridOrderSummaryController : Controller
   {

```
// GET: GridOrderSummary
 public ActionResult GridRowSummary(string ticketId)
 {
   // your code
    return View();
 }
```

}